# Replace content if input has value

Tags: jquery

When an hidden input has a value that contains the letters "LO" I want to replace a button inside a form with some different html.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="LO123456" id="hiddenCode" value="LO123456" />
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="formProductQuantity" value="1" />
<a class="button green" href="#" onclick="$('#form').submit(); return false;">Add to cart</a>
```

So in above example the hidden field has "LO" in it, so how can I replace the button with

```
<a class="button green" href="some.html">More information</a>
```

What I tried:

```
if ($( "input[value*='LO']" ).find('.button').replaceWith('<a class="button green" href="some.html">More information</a>'));
```

That doesn't work though because it replace also the buttons without "LO" in the hidden field.

Any help greatly appreciated!

UPDATED

I've updated the code because there's another input field which I didn't mentioned!

Comment: You don't need the `if` statement at all -- it's a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

`.find('.button')` to `.next('.button')`

`.find()` = find element inside this element

`.next()` = find element next to this element

---

Use `$( "input[value^='LO']")`(input starts with `LO`)

---

You don't need to use `if else statement`

---

Add `:hidden` for more focusing

or use your input id `hiddenCode` *(if you are sure it unique id)*

---

**Finally :**

```
var newButton = '<a class="button green" href="some.html">More information</a>';
$("input:hidden[value^='LO']").next('.button').replaceWith(newButton);
```

Using ID

```
var newButton = '<a class="button green" href="some.html">More information</a>';
$("#hiddenCode").next('.button').replaceWith(newButton);
```

Comment: Thx for your quick and usefull explaination. Unfortunately your code doesn't work. I forgot to mention that there's another input field before the button. Therefore "next" doesn't work??

Comment: `.next().next('.button')` ? @JaapVermoolen

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
var v = $('#hiddenCode').val();
if (v && v.indexOf('LO') > -1) {
  $('.button').replaceWith('<a class="button green" href="some.html">More information</a>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is not needed in: if ($( "input[value*='LO']" )....

You need next instead of find:

```
$( "input[value^='LO']" ).next('.button').replaceWith('<a class="button green" href="some.html">More information</a>');
```

Next searches for the next sibling, find searches for descendents.